# Batch updating using loop on large table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have two tables with overlaping data. One table is about 90% duplicate of the other.  I need to identify the 10% of unique records in a table and move it to it's parent table.  Both of these tables are 400 million + rows with 300+ columns.  The method I am attempting is adding a flag field to uniquely ID the records I need to transfer however I need to update the field and am struggling with the logic.  Below is what I have put together so far and it causes a never ending loop.  There are no null values in either table.

```
Declare @counter int 
Declare @RowsEffected int 
Declare @RowsCnt int 
Declare @Err int
SELECT @COUNTER = 1
SELECT @RowsEffected = 0

while (@counter > 0)
begin
set Rowcount 10000000

update Table1
set Existsflg = 1
where exists (
Select Fields
from Table1
Except
Select Fields
from table2 )

Select @RowsCnt = @@ROWCOUNT , @Err = @@ERROR
If @Err <> 0
begin
Print 'Problem Updating the records'
end
IF @RowsCnt = 0
SELECT @COUNTER = 0 
ELSE
SELECT @RowsEffected = @RowsEffected + @RowsCnt 
PRINT 'The total number of rows effected :'+convert(varchar,@RowsEffected)     
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'        
END 
SET ROWCOUNT 0
Go
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it one time.

I didn't use RowCount, I used Select TOP (N) and "while exists"

My "source" dbo.Employee table was on another server.

```
GO
USE [$(DestinationDatabaseName)]
GO





/*

READ ME !!!

Replace
    $(SourceServer).$(SourceDatabaseName)
With                            (the Server and DatabaseName of the SOURCE data)
    (ex:)  [OtherServer].[OtherDatabase]


*/




--SubFolder: SQLReplicateReplacer
print '[uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer]'
go


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer]
Go


/*


declare @numberRowsAffected  int
declare @ErrorNumber int

exec [dbo].[uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer] @numberRowsAffected output , @ErrorNumber  output

print @numberRowsAffected 
print @ErrorNumber 
print ''

*/



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer] (
@numberRowsAffected int output  --return
,
@ErrorNumber int output
)

AS


SET NOCOUNT ON


select @ErrorNumber = 0


declare @ErrorTracker int 
declare @insertRowCount int
declare @updateRowCount int 
select @insertRowCount = 0
select @updateRowCount = 0





IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employeeupdate') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #Employeeupdate
end






CREATE TABLE #Employeeupdate (  
EmployeeKeyID int IDENTITY (1,1),

EmployeeUUID uniqueidentifier,
EmployeeLabel varchar(64),
EmployeeDescription varchar(128)


)



declare @ManualReplicationRowCount int
/* I put this value in a stored procedure, so I could change it in one place */
/* EXEC dbo.uspInternalSettingGetManualReplicationRowCount @ManualReplicationRowCount output */
Select @ManualReplicationRowCount = 1000 


declare @MaximumLoopCounter int 


select @MaximumLoopCounter = 10000



while (@MaximumLoopCounter > 0) and exists 
(


Select

    TOP 1 null


from [$(SourceServer)].[$(SourceDatabaseName)].dbo.Employee vart with (nolock)


    where not exists
    (
        select null from dbo.Employee   with (nolock)   --  destinationTable
        Where

            /*
            destinationTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN1 = sourceTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN1
            and
            destinationTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN2 = sourceTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN2
            */

dbo.Employee.EmployeeUUID = vart.EmployeeUUID 


    )

)



BEGIN


    select @MaximumLoopCounter = @MaximumLoopCounter - 1




DELETE FROM #Employeeupdate




Insert into #Employeeupdate  
(   
        EmployeeUUID, 
        EmployeeLabel, 
        EmployeeDescription

)

Select

    TOP (@ManualReplicationRowCount)

        EmployeeUUID, 
        EmployeeLabel, 
        EmployeeDescription


    from [$(SourceServer)].[$(SourceDatabaseName)].dbo.Employee vart with (nolock)

    where not exists
    (
        select null from dbo.Employee   with (nolock)   --  destinationTable
        Where

            /*
            destinationTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN1 = sourceTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN1
            and
            destinationTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN2 = sourceTable.SOMEUNIQUECOLUMN2
            */

dbo.Employee.EmployeeUUID = vart.EmployeeUUID 


    )








SET NOCOUNT OFF
Insert into dbo.Employee 
(   
        EmployeeUUID, 
        EmployeeLabel, 
        EmployeeDescription

)

Select

        EmployeeUUID, 
        EmployeeLabel, 
        EmployeeDescription


from 
    #Employeeupdate  


SELECT @insertRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT , @ErrorTracker = @@ERROR

if @ErrorTracker <> 0
    BEGIN

        select @ErrorNumber = @ErrorTracker 
        select @MaximumLoopCounter = 0 --Bail Out !!!
    END



SET NOCOUNT ON




END --End While Loop














/*

SET NOCOUNT OFF

Update dbo.Employee
Set

  --EmployeeUUID = vart.EmployeeUUID,
EmployeeLabel = vart.EmployeeLabel,
EmployeeDescription = vart.EmployeeDescription


From

    dbo.Employee with (nolock) , [$(SourceServer)].[$(SourceDatabaseName)].dbo.Employee vart with (nolock)
Where
        --Relationship
dbo.Employee.EmployeeUUID = vart.EmployeeUUID 




SELECT @updateRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

SET NOCOUNT ON


*/




SELECT @numberRowsAffected = @insertRowCount + @updateRowCount


print '/#Employeeupdate COUNT/'
print @numberRowsAffected 
print '-------------------------'





IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employeeupdate') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #Employeeupdate
end







SET NOCOUNT OFF


GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.uspEmployeeReplicateReplacer TO $(DBUSERNAME)

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you do this in batches of 1M-5M at a time because you have a ton of data to update.

What I would do in this case is:

a) add new column named Processed (bit) that would be updated for all rows that are processed

b) select 1M rows into temp table (this may not be needed but it will make things a bit 
cleaner)

c) insert all non-duplicate records into other table

d) update rows and mark them as processes